# When to use method over computed property setter and vice versa?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

When using Vue.js, when should you use a method or a computed property setter? There seems to be little distinction in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter), or numerous articles. Usually articles present computed property setters as little more than a footnote.

Given that both methods and setters accept parameters, is there a particular reason you'd use one or the other? As far as I can see methods would be all you need.

Edit:

This is literally not a repost because the linked SO answer contains the word setter once and only in vague passing:

> computed properties are converted into a property of the Vue with a getter and sometimes a setter.

Great, so how does this elaborate on the subject of this post, *when to use a SETTER vs a method*?

Comment: Is there question about computed properties vs methods? Because that has been covered several times already

Comment: None of the them discuss my title.

Comment: Alright I'll re-open it. I think your confusion stems from a misunderstanding of what a setter actually is, which is only *part* of a property. A setter doesn't accept parameters, it accepts a single value. You don't "call" a computed property you set it; `this.myComputed = "some value"`, which in turn funnels the value through the defined setter. Most any discussion you will find about properties vs methods in any other language (c# in several SO discussions) apply as well. In Vue, I typically only use a setter when I want to use a computed property in a `v-model` expression.

Answer (score 1):

Computed properties are cached so they can benefit you when it comes to performance. They do not work like methods, as they do not accept arguments.

I use them mostly to modify existing data or make it easier to access nested data.

The part about caching is something that can end up being a hassle. They will always cache unless their direct dependencies change. Properties within computed properties that are within controls blocks will usually not update the computed property(not seen as a direct dependency).

This is something you need to be aware of.

When using things like large `v-for` lists you will want to to take advantage of the caching ability of computed properties since unlike with a method you won't have to perform the logic inside of it over and over, unless the direct dependencies of the computed property change.

Answer (score 0):

Computed properties should be used to display data relative to existing data. While methods should be used to do an action and/or change data.